# How to put "required" a field in XSD creation?

Tags: xsd, optional-parameters, xsd-validation

I'm writing down some XSD file for webservice communication between an application and sharepoint.. I'm trying to make my parameters "REQUIRED" but even if i put minOccurs to 1, they could be not specified..

How can i resolve this problem? Here's one of mine XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="RemoveGroup"
targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/RemoveGroup.xsd"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/RemoveGroup.xsd"
xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/RemoveGroup.xsd"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
<xs:element name="RemoveGroup">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="tt_group_id" type="xs:long" />
    <xs:element name="tt_network_id" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
```

I hope there's a way not to write down houndred of "if (input.Parameter != null)" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `minOccurs="1"` at either the `<element/>` or `<sequence/>` level is the correct thing to do. What specific error are you getting?

**UPDATE**

Actually within a `<sequence/>` parsers should expect exactly one instance of an element

**UPDATE**

Your parser may be emitting errors as events which you need to handle in order to capture the errors - many common parsers have this behaviour.

Something which could cause an error is a null value in the `long` simple type - this type does not allow blanks. If you want to indicate that nulls are allowed you should use `nil=true` from namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

Comment: No error... Just no error raised when parameter is passed as null or is not passed... so i have to control in my code.. I've read specifications and tells that minOccurs="1" is the default value..

Comment: Actually within a sequence that is true - parsers should expect exactly one instance of the element